# Streaming ETL jobs in AWS Glue, How does it cost?

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue, glue-streaming

I want to use AWS Glue job that streams data from kafka source (it runs continuously). How much does it cost ? (let's suppose that we're using the minimum possible DPUs)

Any idea please

Answer (score 0):

The minimum possible DPUs are 2. AWS [charges](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/pricing/) $0.44 per DPU hour. Therefore, running a streaming job would cost you 21.12 per day (60 * 24 * 0.44).

Comment: There is no difference between the normal Spark **mode** and `Spark Streaming mode`  ?!

Comment: Pricing wise, no.